# Can I test an application from iTunes without having a device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, itunes

Can I test any application from Appstore withouting having a device in my hand? Client has given me an application for reference but I dont have a device to test it. Can any one refer some online site etc?

Comment: no, it is not possible, if you have to test an app you need a device

Comment: To be more specific, the app was compiled for ARM architecture.  It is full of instructions that only a CPU running the ARM instruction set can understand.  To run it on any other platform you would need to do two things:  1) Write an ARM emulator and 2) Reverse engineer how iOS decrypts and launches applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No there's no way you can't test actual application.
2. What you can do is see the screen shot. **You'll be able to see at least 5 screens.**
3. Refer the information and description given on iTunes. It'll give you the basic idea about the application.
4. Also, you can refer to help site of that application. Which will also give you some idea of **Concept of the application.**

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** test any iPhone App without having a physical device in your hand. Not even in Simulator.

You need to have a device. No other way.